# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema al enviar un formulario?

Tags: html, bootstrap, nginx

Buenas tardes,

Estoy construyendo un sitio de entrega de correos automizados. En el formulario de contacto, está el problema:

Al momento de rellenar el formulario con todos los campos, respectivamente, e intentar enviarlo con el botón, Nginx retorna un error 405 Método No Permitido.

Intenté añadiendo en mi archivo de configuración la siguiente línea y posteriormente reiniciar Nginx con `service nginx restart`

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```

Sin embargo, el problema no se soluciona.

Algo que he notado es que si envío el formulario sin el campo de dirección de correo no hay ningún error en el procesamiento del formulario de contacto en `/contact.php`, pero si lo relleno con una dirección de correo válida retorna un error.

¿A qué se debe esto?
Este es mi código HTML:

```
<form action="/contact.php" method="post">
<div class=bg-1>
 <div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>
  <p class="text-center"><em>We would love to hear from you!</em></p>
  <div class="row test">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Have any query for us? Drop a note.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email: contact@company.net</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Please provide a brief description of your query..." rows="5" required></textarea>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <br>
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
</form>
```